# ¿Cómo obtener nombres de insignias de usuario por id en discord php?

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de desarrollar un pequeño script que muestre todas las insignias del usuario x discord simplemente ingresando la identificación del usuario, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Esto es lo que muestra la API de php

```
{
"id": "1090372582781497424",
"username": "shaydew",
"avatar": "4bda9edf7144f97f6d4375829662b9c0",
"discriminator": "0001",
"public_flags": 4194561,
"flags": 4194561,
"banner": "a_047a91b3560dff93f74ebfdb6810578b",
"accent_color": null,
"global_name": "shay",
"avatar_decoration": "v2_a_37dc2b53b273a457ff19ac2e3fda7e4c",
"display_name": "shay",
"banner_color": null
}
```

Se supone que "public_flags" obtiene los nombres de las banderas, ahí está el problema, ¿cómo puedo obtenerlo?

Aquí muestro mi pequeño código en php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

    
    $discordId = $_GET["discord_id"];
    $token = "";
    $url = "https://discord.com/api/users/{$discordId}";
    
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Authorization: Bot {$token}\r\n",
            'methods'  => 'GET',
        ),
    );
    
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    if ($response === false) {
        die('Error fetching data from Discord API');
    }
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $response;

    
    
?>
```

Lo que quiero que me muestre es lo siguiente: nombres de las placas

```
HOUSE_BRAVERY
 EARLY_VERIFIED_BOT_DEVELOPER
    ACTIVE_DEVELOPER
```

Alguien podría ayudarme a conseguir los nombres de los badges de x usuario de discord?, desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la [documentación de la API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object-user-flags) las banderas estarían guardadas en forma de bit, específicamente en Shift left (desplazamiento a izquierda), que es lo que significa `<<`.

Para obtener las banderas, puedes construir un array basándote en los valores indicados en la documentación (enlace de más arriba), es decir, calculas cada operación indicada allí y asocias cada dato con dicho valor como clave.

El resultado de cada cálculo da estos valores:

```
1 << 0       1 
1 << 1       2 
1 << 2       4 
1 << 3       8 
1 << 6       64 
1 << 7       128 
1 << 8       256 
1 << 9       512 
1 << 10       1024 
1 << 14       16384 
1 << 16       65536 
1 << 17       131072 
1 << 18       262144 
1 << 19       524288 
1 << 22       4194304
```

A partir de ahí, puedes construir este array:

```
$flags=array(
    1 =>       array('name'=>'STAFF', 'description'=>'Discord Employee'),
    2 =>       array('name'=>'PARTNER', 'description'=>'Partnered Server Owner'),
    4 =>       array('name'=>'HYPESQUAD', 'description'=>'HypeSquad Events Member'),
    8 =>       array('name'=>'BUG_HUNTER_LEVEL_1', 'description'=>'Bug Hunter Level 1'),
    64 =>      array('name'=>'HYPESQUAD_ONLINE_HOUSE_1', 'description'=>'House Bravery Member'),
    128 =>     array('name'=>'HYPESQUAD_ONLINE_HOUSE_2', 'description'=>'House Brilliance Member'),
    256 =>     array('name'=>'HYPESQUAD_ONLINE_HOUSE_3', 'description'=>'House Balance Member'),
    512 =>     array('name'=>'PREMIUM_EARLY_SUPPORTER', 'description'=>'Early Nitro Supporter'),
    1024 =>    array('name'=>'TEAM_PSEUDO_USER', 'description'=>'User is a team'),
    16384 =>   array('name'=>'BUG_HUNTER_LEVEL_2', 'description'=>'Bug Hunter Level 2'),
    65536 =>   array('name'=>'VERIFIED_BOT', 'description'=>'Verified Bot'),
    131072 =>  array('name'=>'VERIFIED_DEVELOPER', 'description'=>'Early Verified Bot Developer'),
    262144 =>  array('name'=>'CERTIFIED_MODERATOR', 'description'=>'Moderator Programs Alumni'),
    524288 =>  array('name'=>'BOT_HTTP_INTERACTIONS', 'description'=>'Bot uses only HTTP interactions and is shown in the online member list'),
    4194304 => array('name'=>'ACTIVE_DEVELOPER', 'description'=>'User is an Active Developer'),
    );
```

— *Perfecto, pero, ¿qué hago con eso?*

Pues hacer una comparación binaria, partiendo del valor decimal que obtienes en `flags`, en este caso `4194561`.

Para ello puedes hacer uso de [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php).

Vamos a hacerlo en una clase, para que sea reutilizable. El meollo del asunto ocurre en el método `getFlags()`

```
class DiscordFlags {
    
    private $flags=
        array(
                1 =>       array('name'=>'STAFF', 'description'=>'Discord Employee'),
                2 =>       array('name'=>'PARTNER', 'description'=>'Partnered Server Owner'),
                4 =>       array('name'=>'HYPESQUAD', 'description'=>'HypeSquad Events Member'),
                8 =>       array('name'=>'BUG_HUNTER_LEVEL_1', 'description'=>'Bug Hunter Level 1'),
                64 =>      array('name'=>'HYPESQUAD_ONLINE_HOUSE_1', 'description'=>'House Bravery Member'),
                128 =>     array('name'=>'HYPESQUAD_ONLINE_HOUSE_2', 'description'=>'House Brilliance Member'),
                256 =>     array('name'=>'HYPESQUAD_ONLINE_HOUSE_3', 'description'=>'House Balance Member'),
                512 =>     array('name'=>'PREMIUM_EARLY_SUPPORTER', 'description'=>'Early Nitro Supporter'),
                1024 =>    array('name'=>'TEAM_PSEUDO_USER', 'description'=>'User is a team'),
                16384 =>   array('name'=>'BUG_HUNTER_LEVEL_2', 'description'=>'Bug Hunter Level 2'),
                65536 =>   array('name'=>'VERIFIED_BOT', 'description'=>'Verified Bot'),
                131072 =>  array('name'=>'VERIFIED_DEVELOPER', 'description'=>'Early Verified Bot Developer'),
                262144 =>  array('name'=>'CERTIFIED_MODERATOR', 'description'=>'Moderator Programs Alumni'),
                524288 =>  array('name'=>'BOT_HTTP_INTERACTIONS', 'description'=>'Bot uses only HTTP interactions and is shown in the online member list'),
                4194304 => array('name'=>'ACTIVE_DEVELOPER', 'description'=>'User is an Active Developer'),
                );

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function getFlags($decimal) {
        return array_filter($this->flags, 
                            function($value, $key) use($decimal) {
                                return ($key & $decimal) > 0;
                            }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
                           );
    }
}
```

Y, para usarla en cualquier contexto, creas una instancia de la clase y le pasas el valor decimal al método `getFlags()`.

Por ejemplo:

```
$mFlags=new DiscordFlags();
if($flags=$mFlags->getFlags(4194561)) {
    foreach ($flags as $flag) {
        printf('name: %-30s %s %s %s',$flag['name'], 'description: ',$flag['description'],PHP_EOL);
    }
} else {
    echo "No se encontraron flags";
}
```

**Salida:**

```
name: STAFF                          description:  Discord Employee 
name: HYPESQUAD_ONLINE_HOUSE_3       description:  House Balance Member 
name: ACTIVE_DEVELOPER               description:  User is an Active Developer
```

#### DEMO

Aquí te dejo un [<kbd>`DEMO`</kbd>](https://rextester.com/TXIT97056) para que puedas hacer pruebas.